# how to deal with and understand Duplicate vertex names error in graph

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I have the following task: Build a directed graph representing the invites network: an individual A is connected to individual B if A invited B to the platform.

To solve it, I tried these lines of code:

```
    all.user <- dt.users[, list(name=unique(user_id), type=FALSE)]
    all.inviter <- dt.users[, list(name=unique(inviter_id), type=TRUE)]
    all.vertices <- rbind(all.user,all.inviter)
    g <- graph.data.frame(dt.users[, list(user_id, inviter_id)],
                      directed=TRUE,
                      vertices=all.vertices)
    g.invites <- bipartite.projection(g)$proj2
```

It yields me the following error message: Error in graph.data.frame(dt.users[, list(user_id, inviter_id)], directed = TRUE, :
Duplicate vertex names

Here is some data of datable dt.users (with only a few rows and the only two relevant columns):

| user_id | inviter_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | NA |
| 5 | NA |
| 6 | NA |
| 7 | NA |
| 8 | NA |
| 9 | NA |
| 10 | NA |
| 11 | NA |
| 12 | NA |
| 13 | NA |
| 14 | NA |
| 15 | NA |
| 16 | NA |
| 17 | 4 |
| 18 | 4 |

Because the inviter_id is the user_id of the inviter, there are duplicates. That is how far I understand the problem.

However, I do not know how to eliminate it and would be grateful for anyone's help.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible dataset rather than a table. One way of producing this is with the `dput` command, which you can learn about here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is caused by `vertices = all.vertices` since it has duplicated `name = 4` but with different values in the `type` column. I guess you can try the code below

```
g <- graph.data.frame(
  dt.users[, list(user_id, replace(inviter_id, is.na(inviter_id), "NA"))],
  directed = TRUE,
  vertices = transform(all.vertices[!duplicated(all.vertices$name)], name = replace(name, is.na(name), "NA"))
)
```